# I need a player to continuously loop an MP3 to a speaker

Tags: mp3-player

I don't want to mess with batteries or recharging and it'll be stationary so it can be plugged in. The player needs to loop a single audio file for about 14 hours, and I want it to play to a speaker unless the speaker in the unit has good sound. It would be nice if I can set a timer so it comes on and turns off automatically. What kind of options do I have?

Edited to add: There's no laptop or PC at the site. I'm looking for a stand-alone player that can run on wall power. When I look at mp3 players, a loop feature isn't listed so I don't know if they can't do it, or if they can and it just isn't important enough to include in the features description.

Edited to add. I was tired of doing google searches to solve my situation so I asked here for recommendations. Having not gotten recommendations that are usable, I'll go back to doing Google searches.

Edited to add: I ended up picking up a SanDisk Clip Jam MP3 player. It loops the file I wanted, I plugged in a pair of computer speakers, and I leave it connected to the charging cord. It doesn't have the timer on/off feature I was hoping for, but that was a wish and not a requirement.

Comment: Most software based MP3 players have looping functionality and can be ran while getting wall power on most laptops and all desktops, but if you want to have the timing with those I think the easiest way to do that is crontab, which is pretty hard to set up. If you want to do it in hardware I think this doesn't exist though

Comment: There's no laptop or PC at the site. I'm looking for a stand-alone player that can run on wall power. When I look at mp3 players, a loop feature isn't listed so I don't know if they can't do it, or if they can and it just isn't important enough to include in the features description.

Comment: Look for an android based device (like an old phone), most music apps will have the loop feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'd likely go with a [Teensy 4.0](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy40.html) and its [Audio Adapter Board](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy3_audio.html).
You can then also program your 14h loop run time.

In a somewhat [similar question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/15936/school-bells-replaced-with-speakers-is-there-a-standalone-dumb-device-that-woul/15940#15940) I've also recommended the [Adafruit Audio FX board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2220) which is available with 2 or 16 MB storage as well as [one with a built-in amplifier](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2217) which may suit your needs.

Comment: I don't know what to do with those circuit boards. How do I apply them to solve my issue?